# Can I stream mp3 files in my iOS app? Or do I have to download the content locally?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, mp3, audio-streaming

I am designing an app that has the ability to play a large number of different mp3 files that are associated with some pdfs. I would rather just stream the mp3 files so I don't have to worry about allowing them to download them onto their device and fill up a bunch of space. Is network streaming possible? Or do I need to have the content local? I have been fiddling with the MPMoviePlayer framework, but I can't get it to work.

It would be very helpful if someone could share some working code.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275990/iphone-sdk-support-for-playing-mp3-files-over-the-network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can just use an `MPMoviePlayerViewController` and set the content URL to the URL of the remote media (video or audio).